# How to reverse a 'rails generate'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-generate

I want to delete all the files it created and roll back any changes made, but not necessarily to the database, but more to the config files.

I'd like to automatically delete all the resource mappings for the model/controller deleted in the routes.rb file and everywhere else that changes might have been made?

Answer (score 1003, accepted):

```
rails destroy controller lalala
rails destroy model yadayada
rails destroy scaffold hohoho
```

Rails 3.2 adds a new `d` shortcut to the command, so now you can write:

```
rails d controller lalala
rails d model yadayada
rails d scaffold hohoho
```

Comment: Btw, how do I use this command to delete a scaffold? The model and controller work fine...but how do I completely reverse a scaffold?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out. Perhaps I was mistyping something. I just ran `rails destroy scaffold lalalal` and that worked.

Comment: @marcamillion Must've been that extra 'L'.

Comment: What about removing files associated with a gem install such as `rails generate <gemname>:install`

Comment: @doug, I don't think that's possible. Your best bet is to just rerun the generator with the `-f` flag to force it to recreate/reedit the files… Then you can see which files it created/changed, and proceed on manually deleting them.

Comment: For destroying controller write plural name (rails d controller comments)

Comment: Wow I wasn't expecting this functionality!  Thought you had to use Git commits throughout

Comment: Why do the steps not include db rollback as well and schema.rb update?

Comment: You yadayada'd over the best part.

Comment: Note that you will have to rollback any migrations created with scaffold before deleting the scaffold itself.

Comment: To destoy generated gem install need to type -> rails destroy <gemname>:install

Answer (score 59):

It's worth mentioning the `-p` flag here ("p" for *pretend*).

If you add this to the command it will simply do a "test" run and show you what files will be deleted without actually deleting them.

```
$ rails d controller welcome -p

  remove  app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
  invoke  erb
  remove    app/views/welcome
  invoke  test_unit
  remove    test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
  invoke  helper
  remove    app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/helpers/welcome_helper_test.rb
  invoke  assets
  invoke    coffee
  remove      app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee
  invoke    scss
  remove      app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss
```

If you're happy with it, run the command again without the `-p` flag.

Comment: I think this is the best answer

Answer (score 26):

`rails destroy controller Controller_name` was returning a bunch of errors. To be able to destroy controller I had to remove related routes in routes.rb. P.S. I'm using rails 3.1

Comment: Please don't summarize your actions unless you intend for this answer to be the selected correct answer.

Answer (score 13):

This is a prototype to generate or destroy a controller or model in Rails:

```
rails generate/destroy controller/model [controller/model Name]
```

For example, if you need to generate a User Controller:

```
rails generate controller User
```

or

```
rails g controller User
```

If you want to destroy the User controller or revert to above action
then use:

```
rails destroy controller User
```

or:

```
rails d controller User
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could use `rails d model/controller/migration ...` to destroy or remove the changes generated by using the `rails generate` command.

For example:

```
rails g model Home name:string
```

creates a model named `home` with attribute `name`. To remove the files and code generated from that command we can use

```
rails d model Home
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use Rails, use `rails d controller Users`.

And, if you use Zeus, use `zeus d controller Users`.

On the other hand, if you are using git or SVN, revert your changes with the commit number. This is much faster.

Answer (score 4):

Before reverting the `rails generate`, please make sure you **rollback the migration** first.

Case 1: if you want to revert scaffold then run this command:

```
rails destroy scaffold MODEL_NAME
```

Case 2: if you want to revert model then run this command:

```
rails destroy model MODEL_NAME
```

Case 3: if you want to revert controller then run this command:

```
rails destroy controller CONTROLLER_NAME
```

Note: you can also use shortcut `d` instead of `destroy`.

Answer (score 3):

You can revert your

```
rails g/generate controller/model/migration xxx
```

output by using:

```
 rails d/destroy controller/model/migration xxx
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to delete the controller manually:

For controller `welcome`

```
rm app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
rm app/views/welcome
rm test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
rm app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
rm test/helpers/welcome_helper_test.rb
rm app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee
rm app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss
```

Answer (score 3):

You can undo a `rails generate` in the following ways:

- For the model: `rails destroy MODEL`
- For the controller: `rails destroy controller_name`

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I have created a controller named "sample" like:

```
rails generate controller sample
```

If I have to destroy this controller, all I have to do is swap `generate` with `destroy`, as in

```
rails destroy controller sample.
```

If you want to reverse the generation, all you have to do is swap  `generate` with `destroy`.

Answer (score 3):

To reverse `rails generate`, use `rails destroy`:

```
rails destroy Model
```

See "[`rails destroy`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-destroy)" for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can destroy all things that was created same way except little thing change.
For controller,

```
rails d controller_name (d stands for destroy)
```

For Model

```
rails d model_name
```

you just put `d(destroy)` instead of `g(generate)` in your migration.

Answer (score 2):

All versions of rails have a "destroy", so-, if you create a (for example) scaffold named "tasks" using a generator, to destroy all the changes of that generate step you will have to type:

```
rails destroy scaffold Tasks
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

To reverse that, we just destroy it. Open the Terminal application and go to the project directory, then, type this:

```
rails destroy model CamelCase
rails destroy controller CamelCase
```

Where `CamelCase` is a name of any model or controller.
It will remove the model, migration and some of the related test files. (You can see the result in the Terminal window after you have run the command.)

Answer (score 0):

Removed scaffolding for selected model:

```
bin/rails d scaffold <AccessControl> //model name
```

Answer (score 0):

We use generate as 
                          `rails generate app`. 
So regenerating any `generate` statement can be reversed using `destroy` statement.
Just replace `generate` with `destroy` 
i.e.      `rails generate app` can be written as   `rails destroy app'`
rails generate ____`as`rails destroy ____`