# Rename columns after migration in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I wonder if there's a fast way that I can update the column names after I did the migration in rails?

For example, in my schema, entity user has a column "user_name", and I changed that to "name" through a migration below:

```
class FixColumnName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :users, :user_name, :name
  end
end
```

Then I ran

```
rake db:migrate
```

However, in other files, say test/users_controller_test.rb, the column name is still "user_name", and I have to modify that manually. I wonder if there's a way to change the name for good?

Comment: If this table was created using rails generate and you are just getting started with the app you can [use rails destroy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161357/how-do-i-reverse-a-rails-generate) to undo the entire generation.

Comment: Thanks, but I have written quite some validations and test for the model and controller. Though I tried to change the names manually but it when I run rake test there are tons of errors. I wonder if rails has a mechanism for such renaming?

Comment: The mechanism is your editor, edit your code to use `name` instead of `user_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way, other than destroying the entire generation, to do this using CLI.

You should use your editor to either find/replace or do more advanced refactoring. For example, in RubyMine, which I use, there is a quite a comprehensive refactoring capability. You can read about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/refactoring-source-code.html).

Goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

Run `vim some path/test/users_controller_test.rb` on your terminal
Press escape 
Type: 
`:%s/user_name/name/g` hit enter
Escape again, type `:x` and hit enter

If you don't want to use vim, I'm sure there's a way to do in whatever text editor you're using. Search find and replace with the name of your editor on Google.